# kdb casting date to day count yield incorrect result

Tags: kdb

[KDB for mortals](http://code.kx.com/wiki/JB%3aQforMortals2/atoms) , so KDB can flexibly convert date to underlying day count.

> Advanced: The underlying day count can be obtained by casting to int.

```
 `int$2000.02.01 
 31
```

This doesn't look correct to me , why convert Feb month yield 31 days ?  or I am reading the document incorrectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It yields the day count since the epoch date (2000.01.01) in kdb+.

Between 2000.01.01 to 2000.02.01, there are 31 days.

Answer (score 1):

WookiKent's answer is correct. To add to this however, if you're looking for some date object type attributes to extract year, month, day as ints, the following may be helpful:

```
dateObject:{`date`year`month`day!x,"I"$"."vs string[x]}
dt:dateObject[2000.02.01]

q)dt[`date]
2000.02.01
q)dt[`year]
2000
q)dt[`month]
2
q)dt[`day]
1
```

Comment: Dot notation should work as well :)
`q)d:.z.d`
`q)d.year`
`2014i`
`q)d.mm`
`4i`
`q)d.dd`
`9i`
but with limitation though...